# On_release Button not working , transitions also not working

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am a complete beginner in code and can't find the problem in my code. This is the main file. I want to transition from the MainWindow to the MakeAcc screen using the button.

But the button doesn't seem to respond to the on_release code. Any suggestions?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager , Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class MakeAcc(Screen):
    current= "login"


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Op(App):
    def build(self):
        return MakeAcc()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Op().run()
```

Here's the KV File. I tried copying a coder's code for seeing if that works and it did but I couldn't find what I was doing wrong. Any Help would be highly appreciated.

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    MakeAcc:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "login"


    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Popeye"
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.3,"top": 1}
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            color: [0,0,0,1]

        Label:
            text: "Email Address:  "
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.1,"top": 0.8}
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            color: [0,0,0,1]



        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.8}


        Label:
            text: "Password:  "
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.1,"top": 0.5}
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            color: [0,0,0,1]


        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.5}

        Button:

            text: "Submit"
            on_press:
                app.root.current = "create"
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.14
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.2}
            background_color: [0,0,0,1]



        Button:

            text: "Don't Have An Account? Create One Today!"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.08
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "top": 0.3}
            background_color: [0,0,0,1]





<MakeAcc>:
     name:"create"


     FloatLayout:
         Label:
            text: "Create An Account"
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.35,"y": 0.8}
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
            color: [0,0,0,1]

        Label:
            text: "Username:  "
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.1,"y": 0.6}
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.07
            color: [0,0,0,1]



        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.07
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.6}


        Label:
            text: "Email:  "
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.1,"y": 0.5}
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.07
            color: [0,0,0,1]


        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.07
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.5}

        Label:
            text: "Password:  "
            pos_hint: { "x": 0.1,"y": 0.4}
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.07
            color: [0,0,0,1]


        TextInput:
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.07
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.4}

        Button:

            text: "Submit"
            size_hint: 0.55, 0.14
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "top": 0.2}
            background_color: [0,0,0,1]
            on_release:
                app.root.current="login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

        Button:

            text: "Already Have An Account? Click Here to Login"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.08
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.33, "top": 0.3}
            background_color: [0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Please refer to kivy documentation. Your kv file structure is completely wrong.
[screen manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html?highlight=screenmanager#module-kivy.uix.screenmanager)

Comment: @AndreiSima Did that and now it's working fine! Thanks :)